# How to quote file name using awk?

Tags: bash

I want output `'filename1','filename2'  ,'filename3' ....`

I m using awk ..but no idea how to print last quoate after filename.
It printing me ,'filename ===>I need ,'filename'

```
ls -ltr | grep -v ^d | sed '1d'| awk '{print "," sprintf("%c", 39) $9}'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you output the second quote the same way you output the first quote?  More seriously, what do you about the file named `Thomas O'Malley`?

Comment: When I see "Column nine of the output of `ls -l`" I want to cry. Try `alias ls="ls -T"` and then your command, for example. I expect you're doing other frightening things, too: Why do you feel the need to produce a list of comma delimited quoted file names? Perhaps your purpose is legitimate, but this smells like "File names with spaces keep screwing up my script. I know, I'll produce a quoted list."

Comment: Please see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` command as:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "'%f',"  | sed s/,$//
```

Comment: the 2nd version will leave a final "," at the end

Comment: This omits all the quotes that were part of the object of the exercise, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -e 'puts Dir["*"].select{|x|test(?f,x)}.join("\47,\47")'
```

else

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed -e ':a N' -e "s@\n@','@" -e 'b a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the printf function http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Basic-Printf.html

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash (probably posix sh, too):

```
comma=
for file in * ; do
    if [ ! -d "$file" ] ; then
        if [ ! -z $comma ] ; then
            printf ","
        fi
        comma=1
        printf "'%s'" "$file"
    fi
done
```

Files with `'` in the name are not accounted for, but nobody else has been doing that either. Presuming that escaping with `\` is correct you could do.

```
comma=
for file in * ; do
    if [ ! -d "$file" ] ; then
        if [ ! -z $comma ] ; then
            printf ","
        fi
        comma=1
        printf "'%s'" "${file//\'/\'}"
    fi
done
```

But some CSV systems would require you to follow write `''` instead, which would be

```
printf "'%s'" "${file//\'/''}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend that you're processing some other data besides the output of `ls`.

```
$ printf "hello\ngoodbye\no'malley\n" | awk '{gsub("\047","\047\\\047\047",$1);printf "%s\047%s\047",comma,$1; comma=","}END{printf "\n"}'
'hello','goodbye','o'\''malley'
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant works fine but I think there should be more elegant way to do it.

ls -1 $1 | cut -d'.' -f1 | awk '{printf "," sprintf("%c", 39) $1 sprintf("%c", 39) "\n" }'| sed '1 s/,*//'

Comment: modified version   find . -type f |cut -d'.' -f2 |cut -d'/' -f2 |awk '{q=sprintf("%c", 39); print ","q $1 q}'|sed '1 s/,*//'